# Error javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5ae7ea68: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: android

Recibo como respuesta el error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5ae7ea68: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer.

Cuando hago una petición *https* usando *volley* en dispositivos android 4.2.2.

Este error me aparece desde que active en mi servidor el certificado SSL.

Comment: Pasa este test https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html ya que parece que tu servidor no soporta el protocolo. Tienes más ayuda en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741405/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-ssl-handshake-aborted-connection-reset-by-peer-while y https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538640/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-read-error-ssl-0x9524b800-i-o-error-during-system?lq=1

Comment: Parece que solo soporta TLS 1.2 y TLS 1.1, como podria solucionar este problema, utilizando otro SSL o añadiendo codigo en mi aplicacion..ya que he probado varias cosas en mi aplicacion y siempre recibo el mismo error...muchas gracias por tu respuesta!!

Comment: Pues hasta aquí llego yo (no se java), deberías editar la pregunta para añadir más información, por ejemplo, la parte de tu código que realiza la conexión y el resultado del test.